# Ubuntu drive not recognized after deleting /tmp folder

Tags: 21.04

I know this question is quite popular but in my case I can't use any of the given advice.

I've accidentally deleted /tmp folder, my PC froze so I had to hard reboot it. Now it won't recognize the drive as bootable. What can I do to fix it?

I have a thumb drive with Ubuntu that I could use but I can't get to my drive with terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that too.  Just recreate `/tmp` with `sudo mkdir` and it should boot again.

Of course you need another bootable device, for example, Ubuntu live USB.  Then you should be able to find the damaged tree with `lsblk` or any similar tool.

Comment: `/tmp` directory permissions are also very important. See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-correct-permissions-for-tmp-i-unintentionally-set-it-all-public-recu